# Process the output of a command using printf "something\r" or echo -e "something"

Tags: bash, rsync

**Simplify version of the Question**

Got this code:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

test1 ()
{
    for i in {1..10} ; do

        sleep 0.03

        printf  "asdfasd $i asdfasd asdfdfdsa \n"
    done
}

test2 ()
{
    for i in {1..10} ; do

        sleep 0.03

        printf  "asdfasd $i asdfasd asdfdfdsa \r"
    done
}

processing ()
{
    printf " $2 "
}

test1 |\
    while read k;
    do
        processing $k
    done
    printf "_test1_ \n"

test2 |\
    while read k;
    do
        echo $k
        processing $k
    done
    printf "_test2_ \n
```

output:

```
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 _test1_
_test2_
```

How can I read(process) the output of test2, to be like the output of test1?

**Original Question**

I want to process all the prints from the command:

`rsync -au --info=progress2 $HOME/test/data $HOME/test/output`

something like:

```
 1,390 1% x.23MB/s 0:00:00 (xfr#61, ir-chk=x/1101)
 1,505 2% x.32MB/s 0:00:00 (xfr#62, ir-chk=x/1103)
 1,181 3% x.40MB/s 0:00:00 (xfr#63, ir-chk=x/1109)
 1,773 3% x.59MB/s 0:00:00 (xfr#64, ir-chk=x/1109)
 1,366 4% x.78MB/s 0:00:00 (xfr#65, ir-chk=x/1109)
```

instead I'm getting (only one line)

```
0 0% 0.00kB/s 0:00:00 (xfr#0, ir-chk=1047/1050)
```

I suppose the command its using `printf "... \r"` or `echo -e "..."`

(The final goal it's get the total percentage and output in a progress bar notification)
PD: In the madness of trying things, I'm on this point.

```sh
#...
pb ()
{
    A=${3::-1}
    CAM=$(($A / 4))
    EAM=$((25 - $CAM ))
    c="─────────────────────────"
    s="                         "
    barra_progreso="${c:0:$CAM} ${s:0:$EAM}"

    dunstify -t 150 -r 2593 -u normal "backup $barra_progreso"
}

stdbuf -o0 rsync -au --info=progress2 $HOME/test/data $HOME/test/output |\
    while read k;
    do
        pb $k
    done

dunstify  -C 2593
```

Code explain

```
$A -> Number from 0 to 100
if A == 0
$barra_progreso -> "                         "
--------
if A == 20
$barra_progreso -> "────                     "
--------
if A == 100
$barra_progreso -> "─────────────────────────"
--------
In my theory its posible make this change and get the output in shell-stdout

    dunstify -t 150 -r 2593 -u normal "backup $barra_progreso"
this
    printf "backup $barra_progreso\r"
```

Comment: What is the expected output of the script - the input to `dunstify ` ?

Comment: yes, everytime rsync updates the output line get the second camp ( 0-100%) and convert in a progress bar of 25 characters to dunstify

Comment: Can you post a sample of the input to dunstify ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to add the `-d $'\r'` option to the `read` builtin
to specify the line separator as `"\r"` instead of newline.
Then you can say the `test2` fragment as:

```
test2 |\
    while read -r -d $'\r' k;
    do
        processing $k
    done
    printf "_test2_ \n"
```

which will produce the same result as `test1`.
As a side note, please remember to put the `-r` option to prevent
the `read` builtin from dropping backslash characters regardless of this issue.
Hope this helps.